# Simple group by with thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I have an `Item` model with a `name` and `user_id`. I would like to search all Items and group by User so I can display each user with their items:

- User 1:

  - Item A
  - Item B
- User 2

  - Item C
- User 3

  - Item D
  - Item E
  - Item D

...

In the console, I try this: ([From the documentation](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#grouping))

```
Item.search({group_by: :user_id, limit: 50}).all
```

And I get this:

```
  Sphinx Query (0.4ms)
  Sphinx  Caught Sphinx exception: can't dup Symbol (0 tries left)
TypeError: can't dup Symbol
from /Users/pinouchon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@gemset/gems/riddle-1.5.6/lib/riddle/client/message.rb:18:in `dup'
```

Same error with this:

```
Item.search({group_by: :user_id, order_group_by: '@count desc'}).each_with_group
```

Search with no group by returns results without any problem.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer: try sending through the attribute name as a string, not a symbol.

The longer answer: that query isn't going to give you the results you want – it'll return one item per user. You'd be better served sorting by user_id instead:

```
items = Item.search(
  :order     => 'user_id ASC, @weight DESC',
  :sort_mode => :extended,
  :limit     => 50
)
```

From there, you could then get the layer of users grouping each items using Ruby/Rails:

```
items.group_by(&:user)
```

Comment: I would like to display my results with two nested foreach. If I just order by user_id, I have to make an ugly condition: `if current_item.user_id != previous_item.user_id, then open new div...`. But I guess I'll go with that...

Comment: [doc for sort_mode :extended here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.7/sorting-modes.html) search for SPH_SORT_EXTENDED

Comment: Just amended my question - you can use the `group_by` method to have items grouped by users, which should make the interface logic cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am trying to make `group_by(&:user)` work. I am struggling with the pagination at the moment...

Comment: Yeah, you may need to make the page sizes really big for this to work reliably - if you want page sizes based on the users rather than items, then it certainly gets trickier...

Comment: My problem is that `group_by(&:user)`returns a hash, and Kaminary has no way of paginating a hash, so I need to manually transform it, which I think is bad.